# Zabbix: Discover unkown hosts

Tags: zabbix

I was wondering if there was any way to turn off the "Discovery: UP" (not "DOWN") email for hosts in a host group, and only email when a new host appears, which is ***not*** in a host group.

The reason we want this, is because we monitor our servers and computers (the computers got into this kind of by accident, but we kinda liked the idea). This, we thought, could give us the opportunity to monitor unknown hosts in the network.

So, is this possible through zabbix, or should we go for a different tool for that purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not directly. Feature request https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-306 would likely make it possible, if implemented.

You could hook off the `dhosts`/`dservices` tables in the database and send out alerts on new entries.`

Comment: Thanks. I'll vote that one and add a comment to give it some sort of attention.

Comment: Note that comments that do not provide new information are mostly just noise, they don't help much. Voting is much more preferred.

Comment: I know, @richlv but I unfortunately do not have enough rep to upvote, only accept answers. I would, but unfortunately can't.

Comment: I meant about the Zabbix issue tracker, specifically referencing the "add a comment to give it some sort of attention" part - that is not a desirable approach. Zabbix issue tracker has voting which is a much better way to express interest.

Comment: Ah, alright. I did that too. Sorry for misunderstanding.